# Time Complexity of comparing the elements in the same array to each other only once?

Tags: time-complexity

I Know that a nested for loop for the same array is in O(n^2) but was wondering what the complexity of comparing each element of an array to all others in the same array just once? Lets say element A is compared to element B, then when its element B's turn to compare to others it doesn't need to compare to A as that was done in the previous step. So with each iteration the array is getting smaller. Is this still O(n^2)?

Something like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(list)-1):
    v = list.pop(0)
    for vi in docs:
        merge(v,vi)
```

Thanks

Comment: The good way to phrase the problem is that we need to compare each element to every element _after_ it.Elements never need to be compared to themselves, and anything that came before will already have been compared to the current element. Your solution solves for this, iterating backwards through the array. 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I always prefer give an answer visually. Nested two for loops for all elements can be thought as a matrix. You will do calculations in number of:

```
n^2 - n
```

which resides in **O(n^2)**. Visually, it will be something like (X's represent calculations):

[image: Full Matrix]

With your approach, it will become a triangular matrix something like (X's represent calculations):

[image: Triangular Matrix]

So you will end up with calculations in amount of:

```
(n-1) x n/2
```

As it can be seen, it is half of previous one, but still resides in **O(n^2)**.

Comment: I believe your answer is wrong. It should be O(n!/(k!(n-k)!)) as in O(n choose k) where n is 10 and k is 2 for the example. And for @mo's problem n would of course vary but k would remain constant at 2. If you do the math for your given graphical example, it comes out to 45, which exactly matches the count of "X".