# Finding a value against all values in a HashMap

Tags: java, for-loop, graph, hashmap, overlap

Ok so I've got a HashMap, and I'm trying to iterate through the map and check over other nodes to see if their values overlap.

For example:
{job1=[[16, 18], [21, 23]], job2=[[16, 17]] There is an overlap [16,18] and [16,17].

In my Node class, it takes a list of NumberPairs, and my NumberPairs class takes a pair of numbers(ints). Anyway, the problem I'm having is I have no idea how to check key values against each other.. any ideas?

So far I've got

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : myVertices.entrySet())
{   

//do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First define our overlapping logic, this could be as simple as:

```
private static boolean overlaps(final NumberPairs first, final NumberPairs second) {
    final boolean before = first.end < second.start;
    final boolean after = first.start > second.end;

    return !before && !after;
}
```

Next iterate over all entries and all their pairs to find if the condition for overlapping matches. Very unoptimized method for doing that would be:

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : myVertices.entrySet()) {
    final Node entryValue = entry.getValue();

    for (final Map.Entry<String, Node> candidate : myVertices.entrySet()) {
        if (entry == candidate) {
            continue; // entry will overlap with itself
        }

        final Node candidateValue = candidate.getValue();

        for (final NumberPairs entryPair : entryValue.pairs) {
            for (final NumberPairs candidatePair : candidateValue.pairs) {
                if (overlaps(entryPair, candidatePair)) {
                    System.out.printf("%s overlaps with %s in the pairs %s and %s\n", entry.getKey(), candidate.getKey(), entryPair, candidatePair);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On small number of Nodes and NodePairs this is well enough, but for larger number of values a [interval tree structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) would be better.

Comment: Well done! Been struggling to come up with something myself for the past half hour.

Comment: Thank you! really good idea for specifying the overlap in a separate method, If i were to use the interval tree structure would it be more efficient than above?

Comment: @Josh123 yes it would be O(log n + m) vs O(n^2*m) in this implementation

Comment: @ZoranRegvart I've decided to implement the interval tree structure. It does say in the wiki that "However, with arbitrarily overlapping intervals, there is no way to compare two intervals for insertion into the tree since orderings sorted by the beginning points or the ending points may be different.", would this still be possible? How would I go about implementing this

Comment: @Josh123 I love your enthusiasm, I would suggest that you stick to the nested for loops solution until you need to optimize. Tackling somewhat involved data structure and algorithm could prove challenging. And the quote you're referring to is in the under the "Naive approach" heading that explains why interval trees are best suited for this kind of problem, not to say that it's unsuitable.

Comment: @ZoranRegvart Ok you've convinced me :P, but is there a way to optimise this solution above to get it running a little bit faster? Note: each number from NumberPairs can be between 0-256, not sure if that helps, but I feel like it might improve performance?

Comment: @Josh123 No not really, comparing every node to every other node will take O(n^2) time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676911/time-complexity-of-comparing-the-elements-in-the-same-array-to-each-other-only-o .

Answer (score 0):

You can use containsValue() method of Map to check the element.I'm assuming Node class and their setter method to explain properly.

```
 HashMap map= new HashMap();
 Node obj = new Node();
 node.setFirst(10);
 node.setLast(20);
 map.put("First Entry",node);
 int value = 16;// assuming to find in map

for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : myVertices.entrySet())
{   
  Node node= entry.getValue();
  if(node.getFirst()==value){

    System.out.println("Value found");
    //do other stuff
   break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Node` and `NumberPair` is structured such:

```
public class Node {
    List <NumberPair> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    // Implementation
}

public class NumberPair {
    int x, y;
    // ctor, getters, setters, etc
}

Map <String, Map<String, Integer>> returnOverlaps(Map <String, Node> myVertices) {
    Map <String, Map<String, Integer> > overlaps = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : myVertices.entrySet())
    {   
        for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry2 : myVertices.entrySet()) {
            compare(entry, entry2, overlaps);                  
        }
    }
  return overlaps;
}

void compare (Map.Entry <String, Integer> entry1, Map.Entry <String, Integer> entry2, Map <String, Map<String, Integer>> overlaps) {
  String key1 = entry1.getKey();
  Map <String, Integer> map = overlaps.get(key1);          
  if (map == null)
      map = new HashMap<>();

  String key2 = entry2.getkey();
  Node node1 = entry1.getValue();
  Node node2 = entry2.getValue();

  if (key1.equals(key2)) {
    // self         
    map.put(key1, node1.getNumbers().size());            
  }
  else {
    map.put(key2, 0);
    for (NumberPair x : node1.getNumbers()) {
      for (NumberPair y : node2.getNumbers()) {
        if (x.first() == y.first()) {              
            // Crude brute force compare, I like 'Zoran Regvart''s approach above of sorting and comparing upper/lower bounds.
            map.put(key2, map.get(key2) + 1 );
        }
      }
    }
  }

 overlaps.put(key1, map);          
 }
```

A bit complicated, here's what `overlaps` looks like.

It maps each jobName to a map, which contains other jobNames with the number of overlaps shared with them

So if you have:

```
job1=[[16, 18], [21, 23]], job2=[[16, 17]], 
job3= [[20, 21]], job4= [[21, 29], [20, 24]], [16, 2]]
```

`overlaps` would look like

```
job1 -> [job1 = 1], [job2 = 1], [job3 = 0], [job4 = 2]
job2 -> [job1 = 1], [job2 = 1], [job3 = 0], [job4 = 2]
job3 -> [job3 = 1], [job2 = 0], [job1 = 0], [job4 = 1]
job4 -> [job3 = 1], [job2 = 0], [job1 = 1], [job4 = 3]
```

if you'd like to check how many overlaps job3 and  job4 share, you'd do

```
(overlaps.get("job3")).get("job4");
```

I haven't tested this, nor is this optimized at all (It doesn't avoid redundant work, e.g. if you've already found the overlaps of job1 with job3, you shouldn't be doing it for job3 and job1.) Seemed an interesting question so I thought I'd give it a shot :)